# App stays active in background all the time, although it shouldn´t Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, background-process, voip

I have a iOS App in which users can create and join video calls. For users to be able to also do other things (like for example browse something in the internet) while they are in a video call i enabled background modes (VoIP etc. enabled in that). My problem is that the app stays active all the time in the background, also when the user isn´t in a video call and the app should not stay active in background. This causes huge battery loss on all devices I have tested my app on. Is there any way to specify when an app should stay active in background and when not?